# Angular $resource update method not found

Tags: angularjs

I'm following the Angular main page and I've extended $resource to add the update method like this:

```
angular.module('user', ['ngResource']).
factory('User', function($resource) {
  var User= $resource('/user/:id', {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });

  User.prototype.update = function(cb) {
    return User.update({  // this line throws the error
      id: this.id
    }, angular.extend({}, this, {
      _id: undefined
    }), cb);
  };
```

However running:

```
$scope.user.update()
```

throws a **TypeError: Object function h(a){v(a||{},this)} has no method 'update'**

I can't see what I'm missing right now, any help appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the issue in fact I need to pass an empty object for the paramDefaults arg:

```
var User= $resource('/user/:id', {}, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend replace `{ }` to `{ id: '@id' }` for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the minified angularjs version, so you have to use to [array notation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). Just inject the required services in an array followed by the function:

```
angular.module('user', ['ngResource']).
factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  var User= $resource('/user/:id', {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });

  User.prototype.update = function(cb) {
    return User.update({
      id: this.id
    }, angular.extend({}, this, {
      _id: undefined
    }), cb);
  });
}]);
```

**Note: the same applies for your directives, controllers, ...**

Comment: Are you saying Angular minified version doesn't behave like the regular one?? Anyway, it doesn't help. Same error.

Comment: Have you read the chapter on dependency injection? AngularJs injects dependencies automatically, but for doing so, it needs to know which arguments from the function is which service. After minification, it cannot do this by name anymore (because functions args became a, b, c, ...), so it looks in the array to know which service maps with which function argument.

Comment: Could you try the non-minified version. Then at least you could see a meaningful error.

Comment: TypeError: Object function Resource(value){
        copy(value || {}, this);
      } has no method 'update' . I don't think the DI changed anything

Comment: What version are you using? 1.0.3?

Comment: Yes. I'm just doing the exact same thing from the mongolab sample on the Angular main page to map the update method to my REST api

Comment: The only diff i see is that you use 'this.id' instead of 'this._id'

Comment: The minification issues have nothing to do with angular itself. They concern *your* code. There is no difference between the full and minimized version of angular except some error message metadata that is stripped out of the minified version.

Answer (score 0):

In resource instances, the method name is prefixed with $.

```
$scope.user.$update({}, cb);
```

Comment: Doesn't help. The problem is not on the $scope.user instance, this prototype update function can be found, but not the one used by it, the User one.